# SWT/JFACE progress bar in splash screen stop update while running external process in application

Tags: swt, jface

I Have problem with application that invoke splash screen with progrss bar during initialization, this is part of code inside my app,

```
try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            pbaw = runTime.exec(cmdGen);
            //pbaw = probuilder.start();
            try {
                String line;
                BufferedReader input =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pbaw.getInputStream()));
                SplashScreen ss= new SplashScreen(Display.getCurrent(), getShell());
                int progress = 0;
                ss.show();
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    ss.setLabel(line);
                    progress+=1;
                    ss.advance(progress);
                    //System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
                }
                input.close();
                ss.destroy(pbaw.waitFor());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my question is why the progrss bar in splash screen can not update while i click in desktop or running other application, but my applicatin can run perfectly, please help ???
here part of my splash scrren code to make it clear,

```
void advance(final int progress) {
                if (!progressBar.isDisposed()) {
                    progressBar.setSelection(progress);//progressBar.getSelection() + progress);
                    progressBar.redraw();
                }
            }

            public void show() {
                mainShell.pack();
                mainShell.open();

            }

            void destroy(int val) {
                if (val==0){
                    splashComposite.dispose();
                    if (appImage != null) {
                        appImage.dispose();
                    }
                    mainShell.dispose();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your code in the User Interface thread and never giving SWT a chance to update. You need to run your reading code in a separate thread and use `Display.asyncExec` to update the splash screen in the UI thread.